# Ударение и произношение слова «хаос»

Tags: орфоэпия

Сегодня утром смотрел выступление Жириновского. Он это слово произносил как [хаос], а мне всегда был привычен вариант [хаус]. Жириновский ставит ударение на [хаОс]. Вот с таким вариантом произношения вообще сложно согласиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта произношения: греческий хАос и римский хаОс, в соответствии с языками-источниками. Можно отметить, что первый вариант встречается чаще.

Также в словаре отмечается необходимость четкого произношения гласных А и О.

Это — ха́ос. В ха́ос черный
Нас влечет, как в срыв, стезя.
Спорим мы иль мы покорны,
Нам сойти с пути нельзя! *(В. Брюсов)*.

А снизу стук, а сбоку гул,
Да всё бесцельней, безымянней...
И мерзок тем, кто не заснул,
ХаОс полусуществований! *(И. Анненский)*.

Слово имеет два значения:

1. бездна-стихия в греческой мифологии (здесь рекомендуется один вариант "хАос");
2. беспорядок, неразбериха, нагромождение.

Дополнение.

Произношение проверено по словарям: И. Резниченко (2009) Современный орфоэпический словарь (рецензент М. Каленчук) и  Л. Введенская (2012) Словарь для работников радио и телевидения.

Answer (score 0):

В орфографическом словаре Лопатина даются два варианта произношения: х**а**ос, -а (мифол.) и х**ао**с, -а (беспорядок)

Comment: А есть ли обращаться к орфографическому словарю, когда речь идет об орфоэпии?

Comment: Tagirix, я вас не понял.

Answer (score 0):

> Жириновский ставит ударение на [хаОс].
>
> Вот с таким вариантом произношения вообще сложно согласиться.

Слово ***хаос*** в знач. "беспорядок, неразбериха" интересно тем, что два наиболее авторитетных в наст. время в части орфоэпических норм словаря дают прямо противоположные рекомендации:

у Зарвы М.В. *("Словарь ударений русского языка")* -- ***хАос,***

у  Каленчук М. Л., Касаткина Л. Л. и Касаткиной Р. Ф.  *("Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты")* -- ***хаОс.***